# AWS Cognito Userpool - Cognito does not perform MFA challenge for Federated users

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication, aws-userpools

I have setup an userpool with two login methods. One using hosted UI with userpool to signup/sign-in users. And ther other using a Federated Identity Provider (IDP). For both login methods(Appclients) I have enabled and used `Code Auth Flow + PKCE` (So the code <-> token exchange could be completely handled by the client - react web frontend).

I have also setup an Identity pool for users' to get temporary credentials to complete the MFA (TOTP) setup from react web frontend.

Now, I could complete the MFA setup - showing the QR code (`AssociateSoftwareToken`), performing `VerifySoftwareToken` (after user gets the one time token using code generator app- google authenticator in my case) and updating userpool for user's preference with `SoftwareTokenMfa` settings.

When users Login using the hosted-UI (with useraccounts created through `Cognito` ), `Cognito`  performs the MFA challenge before redirecting with (oauth) `code`.

But when users logged in using `Federated Login`, `Cognito` redirects the user back to application with `oauth code`.

Is there anyway, I could make `Cognito` perform `MFA` for users logging-in using `Federated Login`?

Comment: I came across this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-totp-mfa/ with the third point listing `It’s not currently possible to have MFA configured for federated users in a user pool.` But this link was last updated in 2020.